# handling the non availability in filter feature AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I implemented the filter feature using angularJS

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.searchedItem" />

‹div ng-if = "vm.searchedItem" class="absolute border scroll-y bg-color-white"
style="max-height: 300px;width: 355px;top : 35px;-index: 99;"
> 
<span class="wid-100 fl p5"
ng-repeat="v in vm.cityList | filter: vm.searchedItem" 
ng-bind ="v.cityName">
</span>
</div>
```

vm.cityList = [{cityName: "London"}, {cityName: "NewYork"}, {cityName:"Delhi"}, {cityName: "Tokyo"}];

I need to handle the case if after filter,
no relevant data is found.
I like to handle the case if, I type NewYork123 in the input,
the ng-bind should show "No data found", as there is none.